# Bash - find and remove all html files but a selected ones

Tags: bash, find

I'd like to do is delete all the html files recursively, omitting `template.html` and `list.html`?

So far I have the following code but I don't know how set these 2 file name exceptions.

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with !

```
find . -type f \( -iname "*.html" ! -iname "template.html" ! -iname "list.html" \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -not:

```
find . -name "*.html" -not -name template.html -not -name list.html -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
find . -type f -iname \*.html ! -iname template.html ! -iname list.html -exec rm -f -- {} +
```